# Salesforce to java integration without API

Tags: java, salesforce

i need to retrieve data from salesforce with java, but i would like to avoid use of API.
Is there any other way to get salesforce data from java application?

thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four primary options for integrating with Salesforce:

1. Use the REST API
2. Use the SOAP API
3. Use Heroku Connect to sync the data to a Heroku Postgres database
4. Use a third-party integration vendor that has support for Salesforce